# Interview Ques - find the KTHSMALLEST element in an unsorted array

Tags: algorithm

This [problem](http://www.interviewbit.com/courses/programming/topics/binary-search/problems/kthsmallest/) asked to find k'th smallest element in an unsorted array of non-negative integers.

Here main problem is memory limit :( Here we can use constant extra space.

First I tried a `O(n^2)` method [without any extra memory] which gave me `TLE`.
Then i tried to use `priority queue` [extra memory] which gave me `MLE` :(

Any idea how to solve the problem with constant extra space and within time limit.

Comment: Can not you sort an array?

Comment: Are you considering recursion space as well ?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri No i can't sort the array

Comment: @sonukumar yes. Although i got the solution. Ali Akber's answer cover my requirments. And now it is AC :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `O(n^2)` method with some pruning, which will make the program like `O(nlogn)` :)

1. Declare two variable `low = maximum value which position is less than k` and `high = lowest value which position is greater than k`
2. Keep track of the `low` and `high` value you already processed.
3. Whenever a new value comes check if it is in the `[low , high]` boundary. If `yes` then process it otherwise skip the value.

That's it :) I think it will pass both `TLE` and `MLE` :)

Have a look at my code :

```
int low=0,high=1e9;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) // n is the total number of element
{
    if(!(A[i]>=low&&A[i]<=high)) // A is the array in which the element are saved
      continue;
    int cnt=0,cnt1=0; // cnt is for the strictly less value and cnt1 for same value. Because value can be duplicate.
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        if(i!=j&&A[i]>A[j])
          cnt++;
        if(A[i]==A[j])
          cnt1++;
        if(cnt>k)
          break;
    }
    if(cnt+cnt1<k)
      low=A[i]+1;
    else if(cnt>=k)
      high=A[i]-1;
    if(cnt<k&&(cnt+cnt1)>=k)
    {
        return A[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do an in-place [Selection Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect).

The idea is similar to [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), but recurse only on the relevant part of the array, not all of it. Note that the algorithm can be implemented with O(1) extra space pretty easily - since it's recursive call is a [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).

This leads to an `O(n)` solution on average case (just be sure to pick a pivot at random in order to make sure you don't fall into pre-designed edge cases such as a sorted list). That can be improved to worst case `O(n)` using [median of median technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians), but with significantly worse constants.

Comment: What about space required for recursion ?

Comment: @sonukumar When done recursively - logarithmic at average case. It can be done iteratively with constant space as well by remembering indices. Most compilers will do this optimization for you anyway, since its [tail recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)

Answer (score 0):

Binary search on the answer for the problem.

2 major observations here :

- Given that all values in the array are of type 'int', their range can be defined as [0, 2^31]. That would be your search space.
- Given a value x, I can always tell in O(n) if the kth smallest element is smaller than x or greater than x.

A rough pseudocode :

```
start = 0, end = 2^31 - 1
while start <= end
  x = (start + end ) / 2
  less = number of elements less than or equal to x
  if less > k
    end = x - 1
  elif less < k
    start = x + 1
  else
    ans = x
    end = x - 1 
return ans
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found a solution that is similar to that of @AliAkber but is slightly easier to understand (I keep track of fewer variables).

It passed all tests on InterviewBit

Here's the code (Java):

```
public int kthsmallest(final List<Integer> a, int k) {
    int lo = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int hi = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int champ = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        int iVal = a.get(i);
        int count = 0;

        if (!(iVal > lo && iVal < hi)) continue;

        for (int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++) {
            if (a.get(j) <= iVal) count++;

            if (count > k) break;
        }

        if (count > k && iVal < hi) hi = iVal;
        if (count < k && iVal > lo) lo = iVal;

        if (count >= k && (champ == -1 || iVal < champ))
            champ = iVal;  
    }

    return champ;
}
```